# Leafletjs doesn't load marker images

Tags: leaflet

I want to put some markers on my map. Those markers are set, but the image doesn't load.

[Marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rH33.png)

If I inspect those elements, Firefox says: "Image could not be loaded"

[Firefox inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uWcQ.png)

I'm not doing much in my code:

```
    leaflet
      .marker([lat, long])
      .bindPopup('Here comes a company name')
      .addTo(map)
```

I also have included the leaflet stylesheet. Why aren't the marker images show up?

Comment: Have you included the Leaflet Marker icon images in an "images" folder alongside the Leaflet CSS file? Are you using a build engine? (E.g. webpack)

Comment: try to remove`'marker-shadow.png` from `src` `<img src="data:image/png;base64,......)marker-shadow.png" />` i think it's the same with the normal marker. Else you can add the blue maker as new Icon to the marker https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/

Comment: I'm using webpack and leaflet as an npm package. So I've imported those stylsheets via an import statement too